# Is it possible to set different textwidths for go code and comment in vim?

Tags: vim, go

For example, `textwidth=100` for go code and `textwidth=80` for go comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With my [OnSyntaxChange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085), you can trigger settings changes based on the syntax element you're currently in.

```
call OnSyntaxChange#Install('GoComment', '^Comment$', 1, 'a')
autocmd User SyntaxGoCommentEnterA setlocal textwidth=80
autocmd User SyntaxGoCommentLeaveA setlocal textwidth=100
```

Put this into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/go.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`. Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType go ...` (for each line) directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.

#### Alternative

A smaller, non-plugin variant would be a custom `gq` mapping that changes `'textwidth'` temporarily, performs the reformatting, and then restores the original value. But that only works for manually triggered reformatting of paragraphs.